# How do you run multiple instances of expressionengine in subdirectories using nginx?

Tags: nginx, expressionengine

I'm trying to setup a dev site for a site built in expressionengine.  I would have preferred to use a subdomain for my dev site, but I don't control the DNS...  So to avoid the hassle I just made a copy in a subdirectory called /~dev/.  Like this:

http://example.com/ <-- main site

http://example.com/~dev/ <-- dev site

I copied the database and updated the config files accordingly, and everything works if I pull up either the main site or dev site home pages.... but as soon as I click any link on the dev site, I get a 'Status: 404 Page Not Found' page.  I'm thinking that nginx just isn't routing requests correctly.  This is my nginx config (in part):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ~^(?<www>.+)\.example\.com$;
    root /data/website;

    index index.php;

    include /etc/nginx/restrictions.conf;

    #dev site
    location /~dev {
           index index.php;
    }
```

I'm not too familiar with nginx (I'm mostly an Apache guy)... so what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Sheesh, I can answer my own question now.  Before posting I had spent nearly an hour googling, searching Stack Overflow, and reading nginx docs to no avail... but as soon as I posted my question, I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262367/converting-an-expressionengine-rewrite-rule-for-and-nginx-server?rq=1) related question pop up in the side bar, which I was able to adapt to my case.  *facepalm*  My solution:

```
    location /~dev {
            if (!-e $request_filename) {
                    rewrite ^/~dev/(.*)$ /~dev/index.php/$1 last;
            }
    }
```